# Second circle inside the first circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cornerradius

I would like to put new circle on the line second bigger circle. 
Below is my code:

```
self.circleView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.circleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.circleView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[self.circleView.layer setCornerRadius:self.contentView.frame.size.width/2];
[self.circleView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.80 green:0.26 blue:0.82 alpha:1].CGColor];
[self.circleView.layer setBorderWidth:5];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.circleView];

self.circleView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width/2,20,20,20)];
self.circleView2.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.circleView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.circleView2];
```

So, result is now:

[image]

Final result show on the photo below:
[image]

Comment: You have a circle, you know its dimensions (center, radius), it's just simple maths to put the small circle on the edge of the bigger one. What's your issue?

Comment: you have to use auto layout. add `constraints` to your `first view` (circle), then put your second view on it and add constraints to it (special `center horizontall` and `vertical`, width and `height`.)

Comment: `self.circleView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width-20,20,20,20)]`

Comment: @zylenv thanks for helping:)self.circleView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width-30,20,20,20)] *